# Display country flag in select country options

Tags: html, css, razor

I am trying to display a country flag next to the text in the select country option at cshtml file, and the span with the icon is not displayed only text is displayed if i add it.
The flags are displayed if i display them with div anywhere on the page but not in the select option

```
.fib {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fi {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.33333333em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.fi:before {
  content: "\00a0";
}
.fi.fis {
  width: 1em;
}
.fi-xx {
  background-image: url(../flags/4x3/xx.svg);
}
.fi-xx.fis {
  background-image: url(../flags/1x1/xx.svg);
}
.fi-ad {
  background-image: url(../flags/4x3/ad.svg);
}
.fi-ad.fis {
  background-image: url(../flags/1x1/ad.svg);
}
.fi-ae {
    background-image: url(../flags/4x3/ae.svg);
    width: 100%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
    height: 100%; /* Adjust the height as needed */
    content: "";
}
.fi-ae.fis {
  background-image: url(../flags/1x1/ae.svg);
}
.fi-af {
    background-image: url(../flags/4x3/af.svg);
    width: 100%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
    height: 100%; /* Adjust the height as needed */
    content: "";
}
.fi-af.fis {
  background-image: url(../flags/1x1/af.svg);
}
.fi-ag {
  background-image: url(../flags/4x3/ag.svg);
///FOR EVERY COUNTRY THERE IS .fi-selector

@{
    Dictionary<string, string> countryCodes = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Afghanistan", "AF"}, {"Albania", "AL"}, {"Algeria", "DZ"}, {"Andorra", "AD"}, {"Angola", "AO"},
        {"Antigua and Barbuda", "AG"}, {"Argentina", "AR"}, {"Armenia", "AM"}, {"Australia", "AU"},
        {"Austria", "AT"}, {"Azerbaijan", "AZ"}, {"Bahamas", "BS"}, {"Bahrain", "BH"}, {"Bangladesh", "BD"},
        {"Barbados", "BB"}, {"Belarus", "BY"}, {"Belgium", "BE"}, {"Belize", "BZ"}, {"Benin", "BJ"},
        {"Bhutan", "BT"}, {"Bolivia", "BO"}, {"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BA"}, {"Botswana", "BW"}, {"Brazil", "BR"},
        {"Brunei", "BN"}, {"Bulgaria", "BG"}, {"Burkina Faso", "BF"}, {"Burundi", "BI"}, {"Cabo Verde", "CV"},
        {"Cambodia", "KH"}, {"Cameroon", "CM"}, {"Canada", "CA"}, {"Central African Republic", "CF"}, {"Chad", "TD"},
        {"Chile", "CL"}, {"China", "CN"}, {"Colombia", "CO"}, {"Comoros", "KM"}, {"Congo", "CG"},
        {"Costa Rica", "CR"}, {"Cote d'Ivoire", "CI"}, {"Croatia", "HR"}, {"Cuba", "CU"}, {"Cyprus", "CY"},
        {"Czech Republic", "CZ"}, {"Democratic Republic of the Congo", "CD"}, {"Denmark", "DK"}, {"Djibouti", "DJ"},
        {"Dominica", "DM"}, {"Dominican Republic", "DO"}, {"Ecuador", "EC"}, {"Egypt", "EG"}, {"El Salvador", "SV"},
        {"Equatorial Guinea", "GQ"}, {"Eritrea", "ER"}, {"Estonia", "EE"}, {"Eswatini", "SZ"}, {"Ethiopia", "ET"},
        {"Fiji", "FJ"}, {"Finland", "FI"}, {"France", "FR"}, {"Gabon", "GA"}, {"Gambia", "GM"}, {"Georgia", "GE"},
        {"Germany", "DE"}, {"Ghana", "GH"}, {"Greece", "GR"}, {"Grenada", "GD"}, {"Guatemala", "GT"},
        {"Guinea", "GN"}, {"Guinea-Bissau", "GW"}, {"Guyana", "GY"}, {"Haiti", "HT"}, {"Honduras", "HN"},
        {"Hungary", "HU"}, {"Iceland", "IS"}, {"India", "IN"}, {"Indonesia", "ID"}, {"Iran", "IR"}, {"Iraq", "IQ"},
        {"Ireland", "IE"}, {"Israel", "IL"}, {"Italy", "IT"}, {"Jamaica", "JM"}, {"Japan", "JP"}, {"Jordan", "JO"},
        {"Kazakhstan", "KZ"}, {"Kenya", "KE"}, {"Kiribati", "KI"}, {"Korea, North", "KP"}, {"Korea, South", "KR"},
        {"Kosovo", "XK"}, {"Kuwait", "KW"}, {"Kyrgyzstan", "KG"}, {"Laos", "LA"}, {"Latvia", "LV"}, {"Lebanon", "LB"},
        {"Lesotho", "LS"}, {"Liberia", "LR"}, {"Libya", "LY"}, {"Liechtenstein", "LI"}, {"Lithuania", "LT"},
        {"Luxembourg", "LU"}, {"Madagascar", "MG"}, {"Malawi", "MW"}, {"Malaysia", "MY"}, {"Maldives", "MV"},
        {"Mali", "ML"}, {"Malta", "MT"}, {"Marshall Islands", "MH"}, {"Mauritania", "MR"}, {"Mauritius", "MU"},
        {"Mexico", "MX"}, {"Micronesia", "FM"}, {"Moldova", "MD"}, {"Monaco", "MC"}, {"Mongolia", "MN"},
        {"Montenegro", "ME"}, {"Morocco", "MA"}, {"Mozambique", "MZ"}, {"Myanmar", "MM"}, {"Namibia", "NA"},
        {"Nauru", "NR"}, {"Nepal", "NP"}, {"Netherlands", "NL"}, {"New Zealand", "NZ"}, {"Nicaragua", "NI"},
        {"Niger", "NE"}, {"Nigeria", "NG"}, {"North Macedonia", "MK"}, {"Norway", "NO"}, {"Oman", "OM"},
        {"Pakistan", "PK"}, {"Palau", "PW"}, {"Palestine", "PS"}, {"Panama", "PA"}, {"Papua New Guinea", "PG"},
        {"Paraguay", "PY"}, {"Peru", "PE"}, {"Philippines", "PH"}, {"Poland", "PL"}, {"Portugal", "PT"}, {"Qatar", "QA"},
        {"Romania", "RO"}, {"Russia", "RU"}, {"Rwanda", "RW"}, {"Saint Kitts and Nevis", "KN"},
        {"Saint Lucia", "LC"}, {"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "VC"}, {"Samoa", "WS"},
        {"San Marino", "SM"}, {"Sao Tome and Principe", "ST"}, {"Saudi Arabia", "SA"}, {"Senegal", "SN"},
        {"Serbia", "RS"}, {"Seychelles", "SC"}, {"Sierra Leone", "SL"}, {"Singapore", "SG"},
        {"Slovakia", "SK"}, {"Slovenia", "SI"}, {"Solomon Islands", "SB"}, {"Somalia", "SO"},
        {"South Africa", "ZA"}, {"South Sudan", "SS"}, {"Spain", "ES"}, {"Sri Lanka", "LK"}, {"Sudan", "SD"},
        {"Suriname", "SR"}, {"Sweden", "SE"}, {"Switzerland", "CH"}, {"Syria", "SY"}, {"Taiwan", "TW"},
        {"Tajikistan", "TJ"}, {"Tanzania", "TZ"}, {"Thailand", "TH"}, {"Timor-Leste", "TL"}, {"Togo", "TG"},
        {"Tonga", "TO"}, {"Trinidad and Tobago", "TT"}, {"Tunisia", "TN"}, {"Turkey", "TR"}, {"Turkmenistan", "TM"},
        {"Tuvalu", "TV"}, {"Uganda", "UG"}, {"Ukraine", "UA"}, {"United Arab Emirates", "AE"},
        {"United Kingdom", "GB"}, {"United States of America", "US"}, {"Uruguay", "UY"}, {"Uzbekistan", "UZ"},
        {"Vanuatu", "VU"}, {"Vatican City", "VA"}, {"Venezuela", "VE"}, {"Vietnam", "VN"}, {"Yemen", "YE"},
        {"Zambia", "ZM"}, {"Zimbabwe", "ZW"}
    };
}
  <select asp-for="Input.Country" id="countryDropdown" class="form-select" aria-label="">
                    
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select a Country</option>
                    @foreach (var country in countryCodes)
                    {
                        string countryName = country.Key;
                        string countryCode = country.Value;
                        <option value="@countryCode">
                            @countryName
                            <span class="fi fi-@countryCode.ToLower()"></span>
                        </option>
                        <span class="fi fi-@countryCode.ToLower()">dr</span>
                    }
                </select>
```

Flags beside the name, got no flag

Comment: Do the `<span>`s render correctly (the class value is correct) if you inspect the page elements with your browser's debugging tools? Your second span has a "dr" content, is that intentional?

Comment: I don't see any reason why any flag should be shown based on that code... Could you please check if all necessary CSS/HTML code is indeed added to the post (and likely remove unrelated code like all C# code in the post)? Consider to re-read the [mre] guidance before making an [edit]...

Comment: This sounds more like a CSS/HTML problem, not a C# problem. Can you post what the rendered HTML output is instead of the code that generates the HTML?

Comment: A vital bit of the problem seems to be missing - that is, the CSS for the f1 etc classes. Do they use something that is not allowed in an option element, eg before pseudo element? And your ‘extra’ span outside the option looks suspicious.

Comment: @gunr2171 the span renders and i can see the text here i put dr to test if dr appends to the option text and it does to all the options but only problem is that the flag is not appearing

Comment: @AHaworth second span is just for testing purpose i did post the css file and as i said if i put the span outside of the select element the flag works on the page

Comment: @ChrisBarr https://prnt.sc/hpACvp7O6o5m

Comment: It is not possible to style an option element with e.g. a before pseudo element or a background image etc. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option These things of course work with a span element. You will need to implement a select/options lookalike using other elements.

Comment: A screenshot is not the rendered HTML, but what @AHaworth says is correct.  That element simply cannot be styled.  If you want to add images into a dropdown list then you will have to use a custom dropdown instead of the native browser dropdown unfortunately.